# Binding source.filter between two strings VB.net

Tags: vb.net, filter, bindingsource

How can I filter a binding source between two strings.
I've tried the following:

```
BindingSource. Filter = "[field]>= '" & value1 & "' and [field] <= '" & value2 & "'"
```

But the result doesn't include the value2.
I can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: String comparisons can be tricky as they are culture specific.  Please provide some sample string values.  Also, what is the underlying data source?  If it is a `DataTable`, make sure that the [CaseSensitive Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.casesensitive(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Locale Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.locale(v=vs.110).aspx) are properly set.

Comment: The string values can be any value. From numeric values in string format to any name or character. Example from a to z. from " " to x. Or from "00" to "30".
The underlying data source is a datatable and I've to filter by several columns. 
I've tried convert the second value to ASC and add 1. Then convert back to string. but when the value is z the result isn't the expected result

Comment: Please provide an actual example that actually demonstrates the issue. Why should we all waste our time trying to work out what might demonstrate the issue when you already know?

Comment: Sorry. But at this moment I don't have any examples on hand. It's not my intention to wasting your time

Comment: make sure `value2` is actually included in the data. Also make sure NONE of your samples have single quotes in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, looking at your code more closely, if what you posted is actually what you're using then I think I can see the issue. You have a space immediately after the first single quote and another immediately before the last one. This:

```
BindingSource.Filter = "[field]>= ' " & value1 & "' and [field] <= '" & value2 & " ' "
```

should actually be this:

```
BindingSource.Filter = "[field]>= '" & value1 & "' and [field] <= '" & value2 & "'"
```

This is a perfect example of why you should use `String.Format` or string interpolation because using multiple `&` operators makes the code less readable and thus more error-prone:

```
BindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[field] >= '{0}' and [field] <= '{1}'", value1, value2)
```

or:

```
BindingSource.Filter = $"[field] >= '{value1}' and [field] <= '{value2}'"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try to do what you say

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help was very useful. Although it did not solved the problem, his comment  helped me a lot. Excuse me for my English.